# java bit shifting

Tags: java

I have the following line in my code :-

```
if (( checker & (1 << val)) ) return false;
```

where checker is of type `int` and val is of type `int`. When I try to compile the same I get the following :-

```
q11.java:38: incompatible types
found   : int
required: boolean
        if (( checker & (1 << val)) ) return false;
                      ^
1 error
```

However if I modify the code to have :-

```
if (( checker & (1 << val)) > 0 ) return false;
```

then I'm able to compile the source. I'm however unable to understand why the code did not work initially. Some pointers on why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

`&` is a unary which applied to a two integers (in your if condition) produces another integer. However, Java requires `boolean` values in conditions.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, your condition must be a boolean i.e. true or false. It cannot be another type.

Your test should be as follow in case val == 31.

```
if ((checker & (1 << val)) != 0) return false;
```

BTW C doesn't have a boolean type as such. It uses an int value.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C and C++, where `if` takes integers (among many other types) and interprets zeros as `false`, Java requires boolean expressions in `if`, `while`, etc. Since `&` is an operation that produces an integer, your first expression is not valid in the condition of the `if`.

When you re-write C conditions like that in Java, you need to add `!= 0`, not `> 0`. Otherwise, integers with the most significant bit set to `1` would fail your check.